# Java library to maintain a process pool

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

I'm working on a Java daemon that requires concurrency: an infinite loop that listens on a job queue (*redis*) and **distributes each job to a worker**. The worker doesn't necessarily have to return a value.

I found **Executors** pretty useful and I am using a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to maintain a number of worker threads.

Though, those workers run 3rd party code which needs to run as **isolated** as possible, avoiding sharing static properties.

My question: is there any Java library/framework that provides features similar to Executors, like:

- worker pools
- automatically adjusted pool size

..but spawning **processes** instead of threads?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I understand that you have 3rd party libraries that you want to run isolated somehow -- so they do not have access to static variables for example.

I would [run your tasks in another `ClassLoader`](http://devx.com/java/Article/31614/1954).  There are web frameworks that use this mechanism to isolate web requests. Passing data between the classloaders is a bit tricky.  I'm not sure how Jetty does it.  Maybe using some sort of socket?  Here's an [interesting article about using `System.out` to share objects](http://tom.conjective.ch/tomtom/space/Sharing+Java+objects+between+class+loader+instances).  Certainly a hack.

---

> My question is: is there any Java library/framework that provides features similar to Executors... but spawning **processes** instead of threads?

Modern operating systems will utilize modern multi-processor architectures to get the most out of Java threads.  Spawning another thread inside of your current process will run on another processor if available and will be *much more* efficient that running that task in a completely separate process, especially something as heavy as another JVM process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gray, I do see your point. In this case though, I need to keep those workers isolated (e.g. prevent sharing of static variables, etc..) and maybe run them in JVMs with different system properties. So my question remains, if I need to run multiple processes (instead of threads), is there a framework that can help?
Also, please review again the title of this Q as what I really ask is if such a framework exists and not if it is wise to use it.

Comment: You could run them in another classloader.  That's what web servers do to isolate the classes.  I'm not sure how you would data pass between the two classloaders.  Maybe using some sort of socket: http://www.devx.com/java/Article/31614/1954

Comment: Thanks @Gray; it seems I have to do some homework, see if this helps and get back to you.

Comment: IMHO, it's easier to avoid using static variables than to try and get inter-process comms working correctly with any sort of high performance.

Comment: It sounds to me @Martin that he's working with 3rd party code or something.

Comment: @MartinJames I agree, but I have no access at all on that part of the code.

Comment: The threads could easily starve each other for memory (particularly if you're in a 32 bit jvm), or call System.exit.  It's also rather hard not to leak classloaders.

Comment: @Samuel Huh?  He's not talking about some huge number of threads so memory starvation should be an issue, `System.exit()` is easy to avoid unless some gross 3rd party library calls it, and I would think you'd only need 2 ClassLoaders which should be easily managed.

Comment: @Gray Since you reviewed the title of this question, please review it again as what I ask is if such a framework exists and not if it is wise to use it. Thanks.

Comment: I know of no such framework @dbalaouras.  I think my answer still applies.

Comment: Sure @Gray, I'm checking your proposal. But I am referring to the title of my question. Unless you don't mind if I update it.

Comment: I would ask a separate question if you want to talk about frameworks.  It's not cool to change the point of the question significantly.  That invalidates all of the answers and removes the knowledge history.

Comment: I didn't see anything about the number of processes or what they would(n't) be doing.

Answer (score 2):

There is project in github to create process pool. Have a look. https://github.com/shri30/ProcessPool

Here is an example:

Sample code:

```
public class UsageExample implements JTask{


    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        //Create a pool with name : UsageExample-Process and number of processes : 3
        ExecutorService pool = ProcessPool.createProcessPool("UsageExample-Process", 3);
        ProcessFuture<TaskStatus> pf1 = pool.submit(Task.class, args);
        ProcessFuture<TaskStatus> pf2 =pool.submit(Task.class, args);
        ProcessFuture<TaskStatus> pf3 =pool.submit(Task.class, args);
        ProcessFuture<TaskStatus> pf4 =pool.submit(Task.class, args);
        ProcessFuture<TaskStatus> pf5 =pool.submit(Task.class, args);
        //the get method blocks the call to get the result
        TaskStatus ts= pf1.get();
        Status status = ts.getStatus();
        if(status == Status.SUCESS){
        //code goes here
        }

        TaskStatus ts2= pf2.get();
        Status status2 = ts.getStatus();
        if(status == Status.SUCESS){
        //code goes here
        }


        TaskStatus ts3= pf3.get();
        Status status3 = ts.getStatus();
        if(status == Status.SUCESS){
        //code goes here
        }


        TaskStatus ts4= pf4.get();
        Status status4 = ts.getStatus();
        if(status == Status.SUCESS){
        //code goes here
        }
        //terminate the pool - pass true for graceful termination, the second parameter is minutes
        //wait for task completion
        pool.terminate(true, 3000);
    }


}

class Task implements JTask{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Executing the sample task");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate an actual answer, don't just post external links

Comment: i went ahead and elaborated for ya

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered something like using the ProcessBuilder to manage your isolated process?

```
String myJar = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-classpath", myJar, "package.MainClass");
Process p = pb.start();
```

I don't know if it's a good idea to submit Runnable tasks that manage sub-processes to an Executor, but it may be a solution to isolate your workers.

Comment: hmm..just saw this..interesting idea. I need to check if it works but also any implications with the Executor as you noted. thanks!